# Definition list in html

Tags: html

**HTML noob here!!!**

This is a question which I encountered while I was taking a test on the first chapter of html . I feel that this question is **incorrect**. I just want to make sure of this before I report this to my professors.

[**This the Question**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9s9l.jpg)

Comment: Please post your question here not the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the same snippet of code that is in the question and produces the standard DL output. The only thing missing from the provided dl are the bullet points on the `<dt>` elements- which can be added in CSS (either by using a :before pseudo selector such as .... `dt:before { content:"• "; }`. ....or as I did by setting the `<dt>` to display like a traditional `<li>`)

In short, this is a fine example of how to use a dl - with the dd's providing description of the dt's. If anything, Steve should learn how to indent the code that he writes and not to put all tags in uppercase, but the structure of the dl itself is correct and is a textbook example of when to use a `<dl>` instead of a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

```css
dt{
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: disc;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <dl>
    <dt>Alternate </dt>
      <dd>To change back and forth between conditions, states or actions</dd>
    <dt>Entire </dt>
       <dd>Having all parts or elements, whole, complete</dd>
  </dl>
</body>
```

Comment: so we could say that the question is incorrect as the snippet written by steve is correct for definition list.......and as for the **bullets** none of the given four options would result in a "bullet-ed definition list"?

Comment: I would say that the structure is correct for a dl and since it would be incorrect to mix the dl structure with either a ul or ol structure - the question is definitely wrong IMO. You cannot simply swap dt's or dd's for li's and neither can you swap a dl  for a ul or ol and leave the dt / dd structure. So yeah - its wrong. and it is possible to get the bullets showing as displayed - but that wuld require putting each  dt/dd pair into an li and then breaking the li into the two rows - but not by any method listed as an option.